# Adding index - There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Here's the query I'm trying to run in order to add an index to my new memory optimized table

```
ALTER TABLE [s_Dim_Response_ram]
ADD INDEX response_ram_clientsurveydid NONCLUSTERED ([Clientid],[SurveyDefID])
```

And here's the error that I get:

> There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query.

The server has 32GB of ram on it, and SQL Server is set to use a max of 26GB of ram.

It was upgraded from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2017 over the weekend, so I could try to take advantage of Memory Optimized tables. I made a copy of an existing regular table, and then tried to add a index as shown above.

How do I fix this error? Do I need more memory for SQL Server? Or more free system memory? Are there settings I could change to help?

Comment: There are tons of discussions on this topic. https://www.google.com/search?q=There+is+insufficient+system+memory+in+resource+pool+%27default%27+to+run+this+query&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: @SeanLange I searched but none of them seem to have an answer applicable to my situation and I'm not sure how to move forward. Many peoples questions stem from things like thousands of insert statements in one query - I only have one thing I'm trying to do in mine.

Comment: Can you share some information about the table. What are the datatypes of those two columns? How many rows are in the table? What kind of maintenance tasks have you done after the upgrade? Things like indexes and statistics need to be rebuilt after an upgrade.

Comment: This is an issue for your DBA.   Or if you are the DBA, try posting it here:  dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SeanLange There is 24 million rows in the table, and both columns are ints.

I'm not sure what kind of maintenance was done... Unfortunately the upgrade was outsourced to a consultant who hopefully knew what they were doing but I don't know him.

Comment: I just tried deleting all records from the table and then adding the index - still the same error.